# ajax struts2-dojo-plugin submiting twice

Tags: struts2, dojo

I am using "struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar" this plugin for ajax. But i am facing several problems. Following is my jsp code
I have an HTML button to submit

```
> <button value="Approve" id="BTN_ID"
> onclick="saveUser();">Save</button>
```

Then i call a javascript function as follows on click of save

```
> function saveUser(){  
>   dojo.event.topic.publish("userSaveTopic");
>   $('#BTN_ID').attr('disabled', true);    var
> }
```

And i have an ajax div

```
<sd:div id="SAVE_DIV"
    autoStart="false"
    showLoadingText="false"
    listenTopics="userSaveTopic"
    href="userSaveAction"
    theme="ajax"
    formId="UserCreationForm">
</sd:div>
```

Problem :-
1) The action in `href="userSaveAction"` is executed on the load of HTML form    though i have set `autoStart="false"`
2) The Second problem is that when i actually click on the button to save the data, it is submitted twice & data redundant records are inserted in database.

Please tell me how to solve the **second**  problem on priority

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using listenTopics , i used notifyTopics

Earliear

```
<sd:div id="saveExpense"
showLoadingText="false"
listenTopics="saveClaimDetails"
href="SaveClaimDetail"
theme="ajax"
formId="expenseClaim" >
</sd:div>
```

Now

```
<sd:div id="saveExpense"
showLoadingText="false"
notifyTopics="saveClaimDetails"
href="SaveClaimDetail"
theme="ajax"
formId="expenseClaim" >
</sd:div>
```